# Android table layout with textviews

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

I have my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearlayout01"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/Btn"
    android:background="@drawable/close"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
 </Button>
    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:shrinkColumns="1"
        android:stretchColumns="0"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" >

        <TableRow android:weightSum="2" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:text="@string/HostName"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </TableRow>
         <TableRow android:weightSum="2"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:text="@string/programname"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/programname"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:weightSum="2"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:text="@string/Date"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"

             >


            <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
                android:layout_width="500dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/mainlayout"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-260dp"
               android:layout_marginRight="0dp"

                android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and I got the following output:

[image]

**Update:**

[image]

But my required output should be:

```
|   HostName:     text123    |

|   PName:        text3      |

|   Date:         text6      |
```

Could any one help?

Comment: The screenshot is too small. Can you describe the problem in detail?

Comment: left and right side textviews are adjacent to screen edges,some times I'm not able to  display textview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String, try with this. I have attached the output too. I don't get any irregular text-alignments as I have shown in the below pic.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearlayout01"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/Btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="close">
 </Button>
    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:shrinkColumns="*"  
        android:stretchColumns="*"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" >

       <TableRow  
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="2">  
        <TextView  
            android:id="@+id/TextView04"  
            android:text="Date"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"></TextView>  
        <TextView  
            android:id="@+id/TextView04"  
            android:text="text123"  
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"></TextView>

    </TableRow> 
        <TableRow  
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="2">  
        <TextView  
            android:id="@+id/TextView04"  
            android:text="Date"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"></TextView>  
        <TextView  
            android:id="@+id/TextView04"  
            android:text="text123"  
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"></TextView>

    </TableRow> 

     <TableRow  
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:weightSum="2">  
        <TextView  
            android:id="@+id/TextView04"  
            android:text="Date"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"></TextView>  
        <TextView  
            android:id="@+id/TextView04"  
            android:text="text123"  
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"></TextView>
        </TableRow>


         <TableRow  
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="2">  
        <TextView  
            android:id="@+id/TextView04"  
            android:text="Date"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"></TextView>  
        <TextView  
            android:id="@+id/TextView04"  
            android:text="text123"  
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"></TextView>  

    </TableRow> 



      <TableRow  
        android:id="@+id/tableRow5"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_width="match_parent">


            <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
                android:layout_width="500dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/mainlayout"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-260dp"
               android:layout_marginRight="0dp"

                android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Post back if you have any issues.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <TableRow
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
           android:weightSum="2" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:text="Date"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="text123"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>
```

You must give `android:layout_weight` for both `TextView` in a `TableRow` equally . I think it will solve your   issue

[image]

EDIT :

I just give simple  modifications in your xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearlayout01"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/Btn"
    android:background="@drawable/close"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
 </Button>
    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:shrinkColumns="1"
        android:stretchColumns="0"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" >

        <TableRow android:weightSum="2" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:text="HostName"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="HostName"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </TableRow>
         <TableRow android:weightSum="2"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            >

            <TextView
               android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:text=" programname"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                 android:text=" programname"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:weightSum="2"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:text=" Date"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                 android:text=" date"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"

             >


            <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
                android:layout_width="500dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/mainlayout"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-260dp"
               android:layout_marginRight="0dp"

                android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Screen shot after my modification

[image]

Is this you want ??

Comment: working but,i'm not able to display my 2 textviews in the same line

Comment: @String try this android:layout_height="wrap_content" for table rows

Comment: @String try to give layout_height and layout_width for your table rows

Comment: given,but no effect @edwin

Answer (score 1):

Better try this ..

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rows"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/key"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/row1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="HName" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="HostName" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/row2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="PName" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="ProgramName" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/row3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Date" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Todays Date" />
            </TableRow>


        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: working but,i'm not able to display my 2 textviews in the same line

Comment: text views are displaying in the same line

Comment: sorry i cant get your thought ? better explain in detail