# How to use margin on checkboxes so they will be on each other

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following code:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/availability_sunday"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tile_divider"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_sunday"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sunday:" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkbox_sunday_morning"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_sunday_morning"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Morning"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkbox_sunday_evening"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_sunday_evening"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Evening"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

In a `RelativeLayout`. I would like the layout to be:

```
Sunday     [] Morning [] Evening
Monday     [] Morning [] Evening
...
Thursday   [] Morning [] Evening
```

But If I add the same block for monday I will get:

[image]

Because the work `android:layout_marginStart` and `android:layout_marginLeft`. I want the checkbox to be above each other. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know a lot about Android Studio but try this:
-- Create a TableLayout
-- Put all your data (textView etc) inside it.

*The goal is to keep your data symmetrical (i think).*

[Also check out this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16183390/android-table-layout-with-textviews)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_below="@+id/tile_divider"
    android:id="@+id/availability_sunday"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_sunday"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sunday:" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox_sunday_morning"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_sunday_morning"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Morning"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox_sunday_evening"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_sunday_evening"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Evening"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try Constraint layout it will be easier..

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!--For sunday-->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_sunday"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:text="Sunday:"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/checkbox_sunday_morning"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/checkbox_sunday_morning" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkbox_sunday_morning"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/text_sunday"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_sunday_morning"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
    android:text="Morning"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/checkbox_sunday_morning"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/checkbox_sunday_morning"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/checkbox_sunday_morning" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkbox_sunday_evening"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/text_sunday_morning"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_sunday_evening"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Evening"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/checkbox_sunday_evening"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/checkbox_sunday_evening"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/checkbox_sunday_evening" />
<!--for monday-->
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkbox_monday_morning"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/checkbox_sunday_morning"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/checkbox_sunday_morning" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_monday_morning"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
    android:text="Morning"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/checkbox_monday_morning"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/checkbox_monday_morning"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/checkbox_monday_morning" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkbox_monday_evening"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/checkbox_sunday_evening"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/checkbox_sunday_evening" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_Monday_evening"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Evening"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/checkbox_monday_evening"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/checkbox_monday_evening"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/checkbox_monday_evening" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_monday"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:text="Monday:"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/checkbox_monday_morning"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/checkbox_monday_morning" />
```